# How I will increase the progress bar line according to the count?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a below snippet in which there is a count is increased by one in one second this count will fine but I want to increase the progress line accroding to the count which is in the progress bar:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 secondsStart();
 function secondsStart(){
  var second = 0
  var secondValue;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1000);
  function frame() {
      if (second > 60) {
       clearInterval(id);
      } else {
    $('#seconds').html(second);
    second += 1
    if (second == 60) {
     secondsStart()
    }
      }
  }
 }
});
```

```css
.progress-circle {
   font-size: 20px;
   margin: 20px;
   position: relative; /* so that children can be absolutely positioned */
   padding: 0;
   width: 5em;
   height: 5em;
   background-color: #F2E9E1; 
   border-radius: 50%;
   line-height: 5em;
}

.progress-circle:after{
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.35em;
    left: 0.35em;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 4.3em;
    height: 4.3em;
    background-color: white;
    content: " ";
}
/* Text inside the control */
.progress-circle span {
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 5em;
    width: 5em;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    color: #53777A;
    z-index: 2;
}
.left-half-clipper { 
   /* a round circle */
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 5em;
   height: 5em;
   position: absolute; /* needed for clipping */
   clip: rect(0, 5em, 5em, 2.5em); /* clips the whole left half*/ 
}
/* when p>50, don't clip left half*/
.progress-circle.over50 .left-half-clipper {
   clip: rect(auto,auto,auto,auto);
}
.value-bar {
   /*This is an overlayed square, that is made round with the border radius,
   then it is cut to display only the left half, then rotated clockwise
   to escape the outer clipping path.*/ 
   position: absolute; /*needed for clipping*/
   clip: rect(0, 2.5em, 5em, 0);
   width: 5em;
   height: 5em;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: 0.45em solid #f00; /*The border is 0.35 but making it larger removes visual artifacts */
   /*background-color: #4D642D;*/ /* for debug */
   box-sizing: border-box;
  
}
/* Progress bar filling the whole right half for values above 50% */
.progress-circle.over50 .first50-bar {
   /*Progress bar for the first 50%, filling the whole right half*/
   position: absolute; /*needed for clipping*/
   clip: rect(0, 5em, 5em, 2.5em);
   background-color: #53777A;
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 5em;
   height: 5em;
}
.progress-circle:not(.over50) .first50-bar{ display: none; }


/* Progress bar rotation position */
.progress-circle.p0 .value-bar { display: none; }
.progress-circle.p1 .value-bar { transform: rotate(4deg); }
.progress-circle.p2 .value-bar { transform: rotate(7deg); }
.progress-circle.p3 .value-bar { transform: rotate(11deg); }
.progress-circle.p4 .value-bar { transform: rotate(14deg); }
.progress-circle.p5 .value-bar { transform: rotate(18deg); }
.progress-circle.p6 .value-bar { transform: rotate(22deg); }
.progress-circle.p7 .value-bar { transform: rotate(25deg); }
.progress-circle.p8 .value-bar { transform: rotate(29deg); }
.progress-circle.p9 .value-bar { transform: rotate(32deg); }
.progress-circle.p10 .value-bar { transform: rotate(36deg); }
.progress-circle.p11 .value-bar { transform: rotate(40deg); }
.progress-circle.p12 .value-bar { transform: rotate(43deg); }
.progress-circle.p13 .value-bar { transform: rotate(47deg); }
.progress-circle.p14 .value-bar { transform: rotate(50deg); }
.progress-circle.p15 .value-bar { transform: rotate(54deg); }
.progress-circle.p16 .value-bar { transform: rotate(58deg); }
.progress-circle.p17 .value-bar { transform: rotate(61deg); }
.progress-circle.p18 .value-bar { transform: rotate(65deg); }
.progress-circle.p19 .value-bar { transform: rotate(68deg); }
.progress-circle.p20 .value-bar { transform: rotate(72deg); }
.progress-circle.p21 .value-bar { transform: rotate(76deg); }
.progress-circle.p22 .value-bar { transform: rotate(79deg); }
.progress-circle.p23 .value-bar { transform: rotate(83deg); }
.progress-circle.p24 .value-bar { transform: rotate(86deg); }
.progress-circle.p25 .value-bar { transform: rotate(90deg); }
.progress-circle.p26 .value-bar { transform: rotate(94deg); }
.progress-circle.p27 .value-bar { transform: rotate(97deg); }
.progress-circle.p28 .value-bar { transform: rotate(101deg); }
.progress-circle.p29 .value-bar { transform: rotate(104deg); }
.progress-circle.p30 .value-bar { transform: rotate(108deg); }
.progress-circle.p31 .value-bar { transform: rotate(112deg); }
.progress-circle.p32 .value-bar { transform: rotate(115deg); }
.progress-circle.p33 .value-bar { transform: rotate(119deg); }
.progress-circle.p34 .value-bar { transform: rotate(122deg); }
.progress-circle.p35 .value-bar { transform: rotate(126deg); }
.progress-circle.p36 .value-bar { transform: rotate(130deg); }
.progress-circle.p37 .value-bar { transform: rotate(133deg); }
.progress-circle.p38 .value-bar { transform: rotate(137deg); }
.progress-circle.p39 .value-bar { transform: rotate(140deg); }
.progress-circle.p40 .value-bar { transform: rotate(144deg); }
.progress-circle.p41 .value-bar { transform: rotate(148deg); }
.progress-circle.p42 .value-bar { transform: rotate(151deg); }
.progress-circle.p43 .value-bar { transform: rotate(155deg); }
.progress-circle.p44 .value-bar { transform: rotate(158deg); }
.progress-circle.p45 .value-bar { transform: rotate(162deg); }
.progress-circle.p46 .value-bar { transform: rotate(166deg); }
.progress-circle.p47 .value-bar { transform: rotate(169deg); }
.progress-circle.p48 .value-bar { transform: rotate(173deg); }
.progress-circle.p49 .value-bar { transform: rotate(176deg); }
.progress-circle.p50 .value-bar { transform: rotate(180deg); }
.progress-circle.p51 .value-bar { transform: rotate(184deg); }
.progress-circle.p52 .value-bar { transform: rotate(187deg); }
.progress-circle.p53 .value-bar { transform: rotate(191deg); }
.progress-circle.p54 .value-bar { transform: rotate(194deg); }
.progress-circle.p55 .value-bar { transform: rotate(198deg); }
.progress-circle.p56 .value-bar { transform: rotate(202deg); }
.progress-circle.p57 .value-bar { transform: rotate(205deg); }
.progress-circle.p58 .value-bar { transform: rotate(209deg); }
.progress-circle.p59 .value-bar { transform: rotate(212deg); }
.progress-circle.p60 .value-bar { transform: rotate(216deg); }
.progress-circle.p61 .value-bar { transform: rotate(220deg); }
.progress-circle.p62 .value-bar { transform: rotate(223deg); }
.progress-circle.p63 .value-bar { transform: rotate(227deg); }
.progress-circle.p64 .value-bar { transform: rotate(230deg); }
.progress-circle.p65 .value-bar { transform: rotate(234deg); }
.progress-circle.p66 .value-bar { transform: rotate(238deg); }
.progress-circle.p67 .value-bar { transform: rotate(241deg); }
.progress-circle.p68 .value-bar { transform: rotate(245deg); }
.progress-circle.p69 .value-bar { transform: rotate(248deg); }
.progress-circle.p70 .value-bar { transform: rotate(252deg); }
.progress-circle.p71 .value-bar { transform: rotate(256deg); }
.progress-circle.p72 .value-bar { transform: rotate(259deg); }
.progress-circle.p73 .value-bar { transform: rotate(263deg); }
.progress-circle.p74 .value-bar { transform: rotate(266deg); }
.progress-circle.p75 .value-bar { transform: rotate(270deg); }
.progress-circle.p76 .value-bar { transform: rotate(274deg); }
.progress-circle.p77 .value-bar { transform: rotate(277deg); }
.progress-circle.p78 .value-bar { transform: rotate(281deg); }
.progress-circle.p79 .value-bar { transform: rotate(284deg); }
.progress-circle.p80 .value-bar { transform: rotate(288deg); }
.progress-circle.p81 .value-bar { transform: rotate(292deg); }
.progress-circle.p82 .value-bar { transform: rotate(295deg); }
.progress-circle.p83 .value-bar { transform: rotate(299deg); }
.progress-circle.p84 .value-bar { transform: rotate(302deg); }
.progress-circle.p85 .value-bar { transform: rotate(306deg); }
.progress-circle.p86 .value-bar { transform: rotate(310deg); }
.progress-circle.p87 .value-bar { transform: rotate(313deg); }
.progress-circle.p88 .value-bar { transform: rotate(317deg); }
.progress-circle.p89 .value-bar { transform: rotate(320deg); }
.progress-circle.p90 .value-bar { transform: rotate(324deg); }
.progress-circle.p91 .value-bar { transform: rotate(328deg); }
.progress-circle.p92 .value-bar { transform: rotate(331deg); }
.progress-circle.p93 .value-bar { transform: rotate(335deg); }
.progress-circle.p94 .value-bar { transform: rotate(338deg); }
.progress-circle.p95 .value-bar { transform: rotate(342deg); }
.progress-circle.p96 .value-bar { transform: rotate(346deg); }
.progress-circle.p97 .value-bar { transform: rotate(349deg); }
.progress-circle.p98 .value-bar { transform: rotate(353deg); }
.progress-circle.p99 .value-bar { transform: rotate(356deg); }
.progress-circle.p100 .value-bar { transform: rotate(360deg); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-circle p10">
  <span id="seconds">0</span>
  <div class="left-half-clipper">
   <div class="first50-bar"></div>
   <div class="value-bar"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Can anybody please tell me how this will done. How I will increase the red color progress line in the progress bar according to the count increasing in the progressive circle.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

In looking at your CSS, applying the class `p<number>` is what sets the percentage of fill. For example, applying `p10` to `progress-circle` as you have will fill it 10%.

Let's remove `p10` so that we start with nothing, and add a line that can update the class each second.

```
$('.progress-circle')
    .removeClass("p" + (second-1)) //Remove class p<n-1>
    .addClass("p" + second);       //Add class p<n>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $seconds = $('#seconds');
  var $progressCircle = $(".progress-circle");

  secondsStart();

  function secondsStart() {
    var second = 0
    var secondValue;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 1000);
    $progressCircle.removeClass("over50");

    function frame() {
      if (second > 60) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        $seconds.html(second);
        $progressCircle.removeClass("p" + (second - 1)).addClass("p" + second);
        if (seconds > 50) $progressCircle.addClass("over50");
        second += 1
        if (second == 60) {
          secondsStart()
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.progress-circle {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  /* so that children can be absolutely positioned */
  padding: 0;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  background-color: #F2E9E1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 5em;
}

.progress-circle:after {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.35em;
  left: 0.35em;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 4.3em;
  height: 4.3em;
  background-color: white;
  content: " ";
}


/* Text inside the control */

.progress-circle span {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: #53777A;
  z-index: 2;
}

.left-half-clipper {
  /* a round circle */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  position: absolute;
  /* needed for clipping */
  clip: rect(0, 5em, 5em, 2.5em);
  /* clips the whole left half*/
}


/* when p>50, don't clip left half*/

.progress-circle.over50 .left-half-clipper {
  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
}

.value-bar {
  /*This is an overlayed square, that is made round with the border radius,
   then it is cut to display only the left half, then rotated clockwise
   to escape the outer clipping path.*/
  position: absolute;
  /*needed for clipping*/
  clip: rect(0, 2.5em, 5em, 0);
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.45em solid #f00;
  /*The border is 0.35 but making it larger removes visual artifacts */
  /*background-color: #4D642D;*/
  /* for debug */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Progress bar filling the whole right half for values above 50% */

.progress-circle.over50 .first50-bar {
  /*Progress bar for the first 50%, filling the whole right half*/
  position: absolute;
  /*needed for clipping*/
  clip: rect(0, 5em, 5em, 2.5em);
  background-color: #53777A;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
}

.progress-circle:not(.over50) .first50-bar {
  display: none;
}


/* Progress bar rotation position */

.progress-circle.p0 .value-bar {
  display: none;
}

.progress-circle.p1 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(4deg);
}

.progress-circle.p2 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}

.progress-circle.p3 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(11deg);
}

.progress-circle.p4 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(14deg);
}

.progress-circle.p5 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(18deg);
}

.progress-circle.p6 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(22deg);
}

.progress-circle.p7 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}

.progress-circle.p8 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(29deg);
}

.progress-circle.p9 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(32deg);
}

.progress-circle.p10 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(36deg);
}

.progress-circle.p11 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}

.progress-circle.p12 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(43deg);
}

.progress-circle.p13 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(47deg);
}

.progress-circle.p14 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(50deg);
}

.progress-circle.p15 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(54deg);
}

.progress-circle.p16 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(58deg);
}

.progress-circle.p17 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(61deg);
}

.progress-circle.p18 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(65deg);
}

.progress-circle.p19 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(68deg);
}

.progress-circle.p20 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(72deg);
}

.progress-circle.p21 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(76deg);
}

.progress-circle.p22 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(79deg);
}

.progress-circle.p23 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(83deg);
}

.progress-circle.p24 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(86deg);
}

.progress-circle.p25 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.progress-circle.p26 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(94deg);
}

.progress-circle.p27 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(97deg);
}

.progress-circle.p28 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(101deg);
}

.progress-circle.p29 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(104deg);
}

.progress-circle.p30 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(108deg);
}

.progress-circle.p31 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(112deg);
}

.progress-circle.p32 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(115deg);
}

.progress-circle.p33 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(119deg);
}

.progress-circle.p34 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(122deg);
}

.progress-circle.p35 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(126deg);
}

.progress-circle.p36 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(130deg);
}

.progress-circle.p37 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(133deg);
}

.progress-circle.p38 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(137deg);
}

.progress-circle.p39 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(140deg);
}

.progress-circle.p40 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(144deg);
}

.progress-circle.p41 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(148deg);
}

.progress-circle.p42 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(151deg);
}

.progress-circle.p43 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(155deg);
}

.progress-circle.p44 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(158deg);
}

.progress-circle.p45 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(162deg);
}

.progress-circle.p46 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(166deg);
}

.progress-circle.p47 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(169deg);
}

.progress-circle.p48 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(173deg);
}

.progress-circle.p49 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(176deg);
}

.progress-circle.p50 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.progress-circle.p51 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(184deg);
}

.progress-circle.p52 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(187deg);
}

.progress-circle.p53 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(191deg);
}

.progress-circle.p54 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(194deg);
}

.progress-circle.p55 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(198deg);
}

.progress-circle.p56 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(202deg);
}

.progress-circle.p57 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(205deg);
}

.progress-circle.p58 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(209deg);
}

.progress-circle.p59 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(212deg);
}

.progress-circle.p60 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(216deg);
}

.progress-circle.p61 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(220deg);
}

.progress-circle.p62 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(223deg);
}

.progress-circle.p63 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(227deg);
}

.progress-circle.p64 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(230deg);
}

.progress-circle.p65 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(234deg);
}

.progress-circle.p66 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(238deg);
}

.progress-circle.p67 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(241deg);
}

.progress-circle.p68 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(245deg);
}

.progress-circle.p69 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(248deg);
}

.progress-circle.p70 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(252deg);
}

.progress-circle.p71 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(256deg);
}

.progress-circle.p72 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(259deg);
}

.progress-circle.p73 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(263deg);
}

.progress-circle.p74 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(266deg);
}

.progress-circle.p75 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.progress-circle.p76 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(274deg);
}

.progress-circle.p77 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(277deg);
}

.progress-circle.p78 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(281deg);
}

.progress-circle.p79 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(284deg);
}

.progress-circle.p80 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(288deg);
}

.progress-circle.p81 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(292deg);
}

.progress-circle.p82 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(295deg);
}

.progress-circle.p83 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(299deg);
}

.progress-circle.p84 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(302deg);
}

.progress-circle.p85 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(306deg);
}

.progress-circle.p86 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(310deg);
}

.progress-circle.p87 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(313deg);
}

.progress-circle.p88 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(317deg);
}

.progress-circle.p89 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(320deg);
}

.progress-circle.p90 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(324deg);
}

.progress-circle.p91 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(328deg);
}

.progress-circle.p92 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(331deg);
}

.progress-circle.p93 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(335deg);
}

.progress-circle.p94 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(338deg);
}

.progress-circle.p95 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(342deg);
}

.progress-circle.p96 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(346deg);
}

.progress-circle.p97 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(349deg);
}

.progress-circle.p98 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(353deg);
}

.progress-circle.p99 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(356deg);
}

.progress-circle.p100 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-circle">
  <span id="seconds">0</span>
  <div class="left-half-clipper">
    <div class="first50-bar"></div>
    <div class="value-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you wanted this to be out of `60` instead of `100`, then you would just have to do a bit of math to see what the current percentage is:

```
const maxValue = 60;                         //set the total
var pct = parseInt(second * 100/maxValue);   //calculate percentage of total
$('.progress-circle')
    .attr("class", "")                       //clear all classes
    .addClass("progress-circle")             //keep our progress-circle class
    .addClass("p" + pct);                    //add the correct %
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $seconds = $('#seconds');
  var $progressCircle = $(".progress-circle");
  var maxValue = 60;
  
  secondsStart();

  function secondsStart() {
    var second = 0
    var secondValue;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 1000);

    function frame() {
      if (second > maxValue) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        $seconds.html(second);
        var pct = parseInt(second * 100/maxValue);
        $progressCircle.attr("class", "").addClass("progress-circle").addClass("p" + pct);
        if (pct > 50) $progressCircle.addClass("over50");
        second += 1
        if (second == maxValue) {
          secondsStart()
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.progress-circle {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  /* so that children can be absolutely positioned */
  padding: 0;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  background-color: #F2E9E1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 5em;
}

.progress-circle:after {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.35em;
  left: 0.35em;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 4.3em;
  height: 4.3em;
  background-color: white;
  content: " ";
}


/* Text inside the control */

.progress-circle span {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: #53777A;
  z-index: 2;
}

.left-half-clipper {
  /* a round circle */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  position: absolute;
  /* needed for clipping */
  clip: rect(0, 5em, 5em, 2.5em);
  /* clips the whole left half*/
}


/* when p>50, don't clip left half*/

.progress-circle.over50 .left-half-clipper {
  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
}

.value-bar {
  /*This is an overlayed square, that is made round with the border radius,
   then it is cut to display only the left half, then rotated clockwise
   to escape the outer clipping path.*/
  position: absolute;
  /*needed for clipping*/
  clip: rect(0, 2.5em, 5em, 0);
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.45em solid #f00;
  /*The border is 0.35 but making it larger removes visual artifacts */
  /*background-color: #4D642D;*/
  /* for debug */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Progress bar filling the whole right half for values above 50% */

.progress-circle.over50 .first50-bar {
  /*Progress bar for the first 50%, filling the whole right half*/
  position: absolute;
  /*needed for clipping*/
  clip: rect(0, 5em, 5em, 2.5em);
  background-color: #53777A;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
}

.progress-circle:not(.over50) .first50-bar {
  display: none;
}


/* Progress bar rotation position */

.progress-circle.p0 .value-bar {
  display: none;
}

.progress-circle.p1 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(4deg);
}

.progress-circle.p2 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}

.progress-circle.p3 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(11deg);
}

.progress-circle.p4 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(14deg);
}

.progress-circle.p5 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(18deg);
}

.progress-circle.p6 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(22deg);
}

.progress-circle.p7 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}

.progress-circle.p8 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(29deg);
}

.progress-circle.p9 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(32deg);
}

.progress-circle.p10 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(36deg);
}

.progress-circle.p11 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}

.progress-circle.p12 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(43deg);
}

.progress-circle.p13 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(47deg);
}

.progress-circle.p14 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(50deg);
}

.progress-circle.p15 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(54deg);
}

.progress-circle.p16 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(58deg);
}

.progress-circle.p17 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(61deg);
}

.progress-circle.p18 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(65deg);
}

.progress-circle.p19 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(68deg);
}

.progress-circle.p20 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(72deg);
}

.progress-circle.p21 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(76deg);
}

.progress-circle.p22 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(79deg);
}

.progress-circle.p23 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(83deg);
}

.progress-circle.p24 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(86deg);
}

.progress-circle.p25 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.progress-circle.p26 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(94deg);
}

.progress-circle.p27 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(97deg);
}

.progress-circle.p28 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(101deg);
}

.progress-circle.p29 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(104deg);
}

.progress-circle.p30 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(108deg);
}

.progress-circle.p31 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(112deg);
}

.progress-circle.p32 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(115deg);
}

.progress-circle.p33 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(119deg);
}

.progress-circle.p34 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(122deg);
}

.progress-circle.p35 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(126deg);
}

.progress-circle.p36 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(130deg);
}

.progress-circle.p37 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(133deg);
}

.progress-circle.p38 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(137deg);
}

.progress-circle.p39 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(140deg);
}

.progress-circle.p40 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(144deg);
}

.progress-circle.p41 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(148deg);
}

.progress-circle.p42 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(151deg);
}

.progress-circle.p43 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(155deg);
}

.progress-circle.p44 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(158deg);
}

.progress-circle.p45 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(162deg);
}

.progress-circle.p46 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(166deg);
}

.progress-circle.p47 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(169deg);
}

.progress-circle.p48 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(173deg);
}

.progress-circle.p49 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(176deg);
}

.progress-circle.p50 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.progress-circle.p51 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(184deg);
}

.progress-circle.p52 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(187deg);
}

.progress-circle.p53 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(191deg);
}

.progress-circle.p54 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(194deg);
}

.progress-circle.p55 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(198deg);
}

.progress-circle.p56 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(202deg);
}

.progress-circle.p57 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(205deg);
}

.progress-circle.p58 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(209deg);
}

.progress-circle.p59 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(212deg);
}

.progress-circle.p60 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(216deg);
}

.progress-circle.p61 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(220deg);
}

.progress-circle.p62 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(223deg);
}

.progress-circle.p63 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(227deg);
}

.progress-circle.p64 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(230deg);
}

.progress-circle.p65 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(234deg);
}

.progress-circle.p66 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(238deg);
}

.progress-circle.p67 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(241deg);
}

.progress-circle.p68 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(245deg);
}

.progress-circle.p69 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(248deg);
}

.progress-circle.p70 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(252deg);
}

.progress-circle.p71 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(256deg);
}

.progress-circle.p72 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(259deg);
}

.progress-circle.p73 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(263deg);
}

.progress-circle.p74 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(266deg);
}

.progress-circle.p75 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.progress-circle.p76 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(274deg);
}

.progress-circle.p77 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(277deg);
}

.progress-circle.p78 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(281deg);
}

.progress-circle.p79 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(284deg);
}

.progress-circle.p80 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(288deg);
}

.progress-circle.p81 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(292deg);
}

.progress-circle.p82 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(295deg);
}

.progress-circle.p83 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(299deg);
}

.progress-circle.p84 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(302deg);
}

.progress-circle.p85 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(306deg);
}

.progress-circle.p86 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(310deg);
}

.progress-circle.p87 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(313deg);
}

.progress-circle.p88 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(317deg);
}

.progress-circle.p89 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(320deg);
}

.progress-circle.p90 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(324deg);
}

.progress-circle.p91 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(328deg);
}

.progress-circle.p92 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(331deg);
}

.progress-circle.p93 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(335deg);
}

.progress-circle.p94 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(338deg);
}

.progress-circle.p95 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(342deg);
}

.progress-circle.p96 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(346deg);
}

.progress-circle.p97 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(349deg);
}

.progress-circle.p98 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(353deg);
}

.progress-circle.p99 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(356deg);
}

.progress-circle.p100 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-circle">
  <span id="seconds">0</span>
  <div class="left-half-clipper">
    <div class="first50-bar"></div>
    <div class="value-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Notes:**

- The CSS you have requires that the class `over50` be applied when the percentage exceeds 50%. I've added a line that adds this class when the value exceeds `50`. Additionally, because you have these styled in different colors, you'll notice a green bar appear at >50. If you don't want this, then simply change the green bar to be the same color (red) as the other.
- I've stored the two elements that we're frequently updating as variables in my snippets. This will limit the entire script to two DOM lookups, rather than two DOM lookups *per second*.

Comment: in your first snippet it will fill the half circle on count 50 but after that there is something wrong.   In the second sneppit can you do some change like this that it will complete the full circle?

Comment: @meena Due to the way the CSS works, it looks like the class `over50` must be applied if the percentage goes over 50. I've put this line in to account for that: `if (pct > 50) $progressCircle.addClass("over50");`

Comment: here you add a new css in the second snippet? right

Comment: What do you mean? The code you've written starts it over when it's complete. If you don't want it to start over, then remove this: `if (second == maxValue) { secondsStart(); }`